# PHP Save new item to Switch Statement

Tags: php

I am currently working on a Banlist for my game, and it is currently functional, but I want to know if there is a way to use post ex: http://example.com/banlist?newentry=SAVETHIS
and save into a new case in the switch statement.

Basically, I want to store the "SAVETHIS" after the newentry into a brand new case.

Here's an image to help you understand what I mean.
[image]

Comment: So when `newentry` is loaded you want to store its value in your file? This seems like something a DB would be better for. You also could us an array of banned numbers and then `in_array`.

Comment: Code should be static, unchanging. *Data* is changing. Data is stored in a database or other separate storage. Data is not code.

Answer (score 1):

You need some type of storage instead of writing a code that writes itself.

```
if(isset($_GET['newentry'])){
  if(file_put_contents('./banlist.txt', $_GET['newentry'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND) === false){
      die('no perms, cant create file in '.getcwd());
  } else {
    die('user banned');
  }
} elseif(isset($_GET['id'])){
  if(in_array($_GET['id'], explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('./banlist.txt')))){
    die('user is banned');
  }
}
```

See this as an **EXAMPLE** code, preferred is to use a database and put this code behind a login wall of some sorts as it has **NO SECURITY** checks.

In its current state, if I know the location of this script I can simply create a loop and ban every user in range of 0 to MAX_INT. Also it does not check if the user is already banned, so I can fill up your hard drive by looping a simple script to infinity. Noor does it check for potential XXS attacks.